# How to get put_time into a variable

Tags: c++

I have a function as

```
transTime() 
{ 
  time_t const now_c = time(NULL); 
  cout << put_time(localtime(&now_c), "%a %d %b %Y - %I:%M:%S%p"); 
}
```

I'm trying to save the value returned into a variable such that I can do something like

```
string myTime = put_time(localtime(&now_c), "%a %d %b %Y - %I:%M:%S%p");
```

I need to use the same instance of myTime for two different insertions.

Edit/Update:

After using stringstream,

```
string transTime()
{
   stringstream transTime;
   time_t const now_c = time(NULL);
   transTime << put_time(localtime(&now_c), "%a %d %b %Y - %I:%M:%S%p");
   string myTime = transTime.str();
  //transTime >> myTime;
   return  myTime;
}
```

When I use call the function, I get `Tue` alone, instead of the complete date and time.
Most likely has to do with getline, not sure how to implement that.
Any help ?

Comment: @user657267 Please see question update.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use a `stringstream` to capture the `localtime()`'s output, you can store the string stored in `stringstream` by using `.str()`.

That is,

```
string myTime = transTime.str();
return myTime;
```

Comment: Actually, using `.str()` stores the *entire* string, unlike ` >> ` which has a space delimiter. Can you post the complete code please?

Answer (score 5):

Some C++ API could use a bit more calling convention consistency <sup>(1)</sup> - it looks like `std::put_time()` is meant only for streams, because it is meant for localization - so it can take advantage of the locale setting imbued into the stream, so while it is easy to use - it is not actually meant for general consumption outside the context of localized streams.

In essence, calling [`std::put_time()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/put_time) should provide the same output as calling [`std::strftime`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/strftime) - even though the latter has a much more annoying API (see <sup>(1)</sup>) and for the life of me I can't understand why it can't just return correctly sized `std::string` objects (like other API e.g. `std::to_string()`).

That being said, here's a *slightly* less annoying way to use C++ standard library date-time formatting to create `std::string`s:

```cpp
std::time_t t = std::time(nullptr);
std::string datetime(100,0);
datetime.resize(std::strftime(&datetime[0], datetime.size(), 
    "%a %d %b %Y - %I:%M:%S%p", std::localtime(&t)));
```

Make sure `100` (or whatever you put in) is enough chars for your format, otherwise you'd get an empty string. `strftime` does not allow you to check how much space you'd need, except iteratively (see <sup>(1)</sup> again).

BTW - in the bright C++20 future<sup>(2)</sup> we could simply<sup>(3)</sup> do:

```cpp
using std::chrono::seconds, std::chrono::days;
auto time = std::chrono::floor<seconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now());
auto today = std::chrono::floor<days>(time);
std::string datetime = std::format("{0:%a %d %b %Y} - {1:%H:%M:%S}",
                                   std::chrono::year_month_day{today},
                                   std::chrono::hh_mm_ss{time - today});
```

But to my knowledge, this is not yet available anywhere.

Notes:

1. Why `std::localtime()` takes a pointer instead of a reference is completely beyond me and it requires you to write more code and handle more temporary variables than needed. `std::put_time()` does not require you to preallocate memory, but `std::strftime()` does for the exact same functionality.
2. see [P1361R2](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1361r2.pdf)
3. For some values of "simply".

Comment: C++20 is coming online: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/varxsY1c5

Comment: @HowardHinnant - I already have both GCC and clang with C++20 support on my system, but P1361R2 is completely unimplemented in libstdc++ (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#table.cxx20_features), and weirdly broken in libc++ 15 (so many errors I just couldn't bother).

Comment: For gcc the last bits just got pushed to trunk yesterday.  Note that I'm using trunk in the godbolt link.  So one can experiment with it online, and it should be available in upcoming releases.

Comment: Right - I was confused by the way godbolt shows the output, so it looked like just errors for me. With that support in place, I played with the C++20 sample code to be more to my liking. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you need to use the tm structure included in most if not all compiler standard libraries, then you can pass the data from the 'tm' object to a string:

```
    string transTime() 
    {
        time_t rawtime;
        struct tm * timeContext;

        string temp;
        stringstream textStream;

        time(&rawtime);

        timeContext = localtime(&rawtime);

        textStream << asctime(timeContext);
        temp = textStream.str();

        return temp;    
    }
```

Comment: `asctime` is marked as obsolete by posix. Use `strftime` instead since its better usage and support for locale.